# Query Environment Variables values defined in Jenkins Global Properties using API

Tags: java, api, jenkins, properties, environment-variables

I have configured an environment variable under:

> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties.

I'm able to use the environment variable in my jobs but I can't seem to find a way to query it remotely using the API.

Is it displayed anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

We are setting global environments like this:

```
for (nodeproperty in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.globalNodeProperties) {
    siteSpecific.global_environment.each {key, value ->
        println "INFO: Adding: ${key}:${value}"
        nodeproperty.getEnvVars().put(key, value)
    }

    hudson.model.Hudson.instance.save()
}
```

So you should be able to read them the same way, but it not through the api, couldn't find a way for that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this is not the answer I was looking for

Comment: Ok, I never found it through the api, as I said, so that the reason we used groovy instead. Could you explain how you intend to use the information?

Comment: As an update mechanism.  I write the version there using environment variable